# Read PHP Session data in node.js

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, session

I am working on a project in php and node.js. I have some data in session like

```
[user]= ARRAY([0]=> stdClass Object([username] => XXX, [app_id] -> XXX))
```

Now i want to read app_id from session and need to use in node.js like

```
var myquery =
            "SELECT count(cs.id ) AS new_message " + 
            "FROM dcms_corr_status as cs " +
            "LEFT JOIN `dcms_user` as u ON `u`.`appointment_ref_no` = `cs`.`appointment_ref_no` "+
            "WHERE `cs`.`appointment_ref_no` = '" + user_app +"' AND `cs`.`isread` = 0 " +
            "AND `cs`.`action_or_info` = 1";
var query = connection.query(myquery),
```

where user_app is my session data.

How can i do that?

Comment: You'll need to use an external database/cache for a session store, such as Redis or Memcached. Get PHP to store the session data and retrieve it with Node.

Comment: May also want to encode it to JSON so node can better understand it.

Comment: This solution may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51754896/1274820

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to parse a PHP session file in node you could try [groan](https://github.com/mscdex/groan). Otherwise you might look into using [MySQL](https://github.com/sprain/PHP-MySQL-Session-Handler), [memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php), or [Redis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis) for your session storage instead.