# Using PHP session between apache and websocket server

Tags: php, session, websocket, chat

I am using websocket code from https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat

I already have my custom users account with Mysql where user logs in at *login.php* connected to websocket. Thus I set session/cookie for the particular user. For an example

```
$_SESSION["user"] = 'xyz';//User is created.
```

The issue is when I try to use **$_SESSION** even with *session_id()*. I failed to get **$_SESSION** values. I am doing this in *server.php*  which is suppose to be running with **php server.php** command. I try code below.

```
session_id("lsjdfjl');
@session_start();
$user = $_SESSION["user"];
```

And I get error message saying *undefine index ...*

Is there any alternative way to combine above Websocket server with custom user datab ase and create seperate chatroom for different logged in users. For example FB chat/gmail chat system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use same session.

You can't use session for websocket connection at all.

Websocket connection is a separate connection, on different port, so your main session is not available there.

You need to read about token-based websocket auth. Here is some info to start from https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/

Comment: I cannot use **GET ** method in function wsOnMessage in server.php. Can you show me way to use GET. Oh I am new to websocket.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer isn't really accurate.

You can use the same session data - see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49802049/1274820

I will post code and image here too for posterity and to avoid link rot:

```
var cookie = require('cookie');
var fs = require('fs');
var phpUnserialize = require('php-unserialize');

//This should point to your php session directory.
//My php.ini says session.save_path = "${US_ROOTF}/tmp"
var SESS_PATH = "C:/SomeDirectory/WhereYourPHPIs/tmp/";

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //I just check if cookies are a string - may be better method
    if(typeof socket.handshake.headers.cookie === "string") {
        var sid = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
        if(typeof sid.PHPSESSID === "undefined") {
          console.log("Undefined PHPSESSID");
        }
        else {
            console.log("PHP Session ID: " + sid.PHPSESSID);
            fs.readFile(SESS_PATH + "sess_" + sid.PHPSESSID, 'utf-8', function(err,data) {
                if(!err) {
                    console.log("Session Data:");
                    var sd = phpUnserialize.unserializeSession(data);
                    console.log(sd);
                }
                else {
                   console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Results:**

[image: Results]