# NPM: how to use groan and where to get the php session file name

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to access php session in nodejs

I searched online and found [Read PHP Session data in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676031/read-php-session-data-in-node-js)

and used the sample code from https://www.npmjs.com/package/groan

but it shows the following error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/tmpsess_1234567890abcdef'

Comment: Do you have a valid session named `/tmpsess_1234567890abcdef` and running in your `PHP` server?

Comment: no @David R bro

Comment: After looking at `groan`'s github page, I could understand you've used the same session provided there in the example, (CharlieBrown also pointed it out). Try replacing a `real` existing session with the one that you're trying now.

Comment: @David R yes, I used same temp file name because I don't know how to get the php session file name.. please tell me how to get it.

Comment: I hope you will having the session mechanism in your site, and you would be having `session_start();` somewhere in your code, check for that, and output it using `echo session_id();` you'll be able to receive it

Answer (score 0):

That's because you pasted the SAMPLE code from the repo. You should probably get that ID (the `1234567890abcdef`) from the client cookie where PHP stores the session, and then use that to verify that the file exists and use the parser to retrieve the object.